# How to access to an object by id in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I passed the id of the 'artista' table to this view:

```
@extends('layouts.dashboard')

@section('content')
<h1>{{id}}</h1>

@endsection
```

From the id I want to access to the other attributes of the table. Below other parts of my code which can make easier to understand the situation:

My web.php:

```
Route::get('/result/artista/{id}', 'LiveSearch@result')->name('artista');
```

My controller:

```
public function result($id)
{
    return view('result/artista')->with('id', $id);
}
```

in the same controller in another function:

```
$artisti = DB::table('artista')
                ->where('nome', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                ->get();

foreach($artisti as $row) {
                $artists .= '
            <a href="'.route('artista', ['id' => $row->id]).'" class="dropdown-item">'.$row->nome.'</a>
            ';
            }
```

Comment: The first checkout that is  ' $artista ' contains the id?  And The get method returns the result in the Array. So maybe there is an accessibility issue.

Comment: Don't put a query in a view. That sort of logic does not belong in the view layer, at all. If there's a repetitive query that is called in many places that use the same view, take a look at view composers. Otherwise, put the query elsewhere and pass it into the view.

Comment: @MatthewDaly How can I do it different? I mean I have passed the id to the view by a link. How can I use this id to access to all the other element of the object?

Comment: @FridRic Do it in the controller and pass it into the view from there - this is basic stuff in Laravel and [is covered by the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#basic-controllers). If this is in a view that is used in more than one place, look at the [documentation on view composers](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#view-composers), again in the Laravel documentation

Comment: @MatthewDaly thank you for you answer, I have edited my question with more elements so you can make other observations

Comment: @FridRic The way you're passing the name into the view instead of the items is problematic. You should never, ever make a query in a view - it's a violation of the whole MVC pattern. Instead you should move the query to the controller, and pass the response retrieved by it into the view.

Comment: The last snippet is from another function of the controller

Comment: @MatthewDaly I have edited the question properly due to your observations which were very useful. Please check it and thank you

Comment: You want data from `artista` table by the `id` from another route ? is this your question and then you want that to be present in `result.blade.php` ?

Comment: Yes it is @AkhtarMunir

Comment: @FridRic see answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So you have another question right ? Well I had solved your question of the route id to pass to another view. But now i think you want data related to that `id`. If I am not wrong.

**In your controller method**

```
public function result($id)
{
   $artista = DB::table('artista')->where('id', $id)->first();
   return view('result/artista', compact('artista'));
}
```

**In your view access like this**

```
@extends('layouts.dashboard')

@section('content')

<h1>{{ $artista->id }}</h1>
<h1>{{ $artista->nome }}</h1>//More data from your table you can access

@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you can pass the database from routes like:

```
Route::get('{id}', function($id){
        $artista = DB::table('artista')->where('id', 'like', '%'.$id.'%')->first();
        return view('....', compact('artista'));
      });
```

or pass it in controller.

and inside view:

```
@extends('layouts.dashboard')

@section('content')
<h1>{{$artista->id}}</h1>

@endsection
```

Comment: use **=** instead of **LIKE %%**, because _id_ is unique

Comment: In this way I pass to the view the object and not just the id. I've edited the question with other elements useful to understand the situation

Comment: I have edited the question propertly. Please check it.

Comment: `where('id', 'like', '%'.$id.'%')` - that does not make sense